# Как раздробить раздел в elementary OS в GParted?

Tags: linux, hdd, elementary-os

Всем привет. Заранее хочу что только постигаю linux и пока еще не особо в ней силен. Вообщем мне нужно раздробить раздел sda2 на 2 части. Насколько я понял, это делается с помощью "Изменить раздел/переместить", но у меня написано что этот раздел полностью использован. Хотя он вроде как не полностью занят. Объясните пожалуйста что нужно сделать, что бы его разделить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. в данном случае гораздо полезнее был бы вывод команды `$ sudo fdisk -l`. 2. уменьшить размер physical volume, конечно, можно, но в данном вашем случае придётся предварительно уменьшать размер файловой(-ых) системы(-м), logical volumes и volume group. 3. поэтому может быть вам проще и лучше было бы «порулить» [подсистемой lvm](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/LVM), раз она у вас всё равно используется?

Comment: Если вы решили использовать LVM, значит и уменьшать нужно тоже с участием LVM https://askubuntu.com/questions/196125